# Odd behaviour in ie8 when an anchor tag comes first in a block element

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, anchor, block

In ie8 when I have an anchor first thing within a block element, you can hover over the end of the block element and it links to that anchor. This is very annoying and I have no idea how to fix it. In the following example, I removed all javascript and css.

```
<p><a href="http://www.gamefaqs.com/-/199180-">Vandal Hearts II</a> is a turn-based strategy RPG for PlayStation that was released in 1999.</p>
```

[(Example Image)](http://www.heresmary.com/Untitled.png)

More info: When I put a character before the  it does not have this behaviour. I tried using a space and putting the code on different lines, etc, and none of that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be a `p` tag? As a `span` tag would be better suited here plus it solves that problem, as you can see in this Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/gmUe3/).

Comment: All block elements have this behaviour and I need it in a block element. I surrounded the <a> with <span></span> while still having it in the <p> and that works, but I would rather not do that.

Comment: I tried it with the `<p>` in a previous Fiddle, that didn't work. I then tried it with the `<span>` as shown in my Fiddle I posted and that worked for me. Did it not work for you?

Comment: It worked, but this also worked (which is better for me): "I surrounded the <a> with <span></span> while still having it in the <p>"

Is there a better way to do it? Does anyone know why this happens in ie8?

Comment: Ah okay, any reason why it worked better for you? Or is it just preference? :)

Comment: Preference, but obviously I would rather have no extra markup. Maybe I'll just not use anchors first thing in block elements.

Comment: Ah fair enough, personally I'd stick with just `span`, no extra markup needed plus there's no strange issues with IE8 :).